# Returning selected data to drop down form element consisting of key value pairs

Tags: html, go, range, dropdown, key-value

I am new to Golang.
I have form with drop down element consisting of key value pairs. When I submit my form, it fails validation (The failure has nothing to do with the drop down element).
I have to send back all correct captured date including the item selected on drop down item of my form.

I have not been to do this. How does one send back what was selected? My html is shown below.

```
<div> 
   {{ with .Errors.Size }}
       <p class="error text-danger">{{ . }}</p>
   {{ end }}
   <label for="size" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Size</label>
      <select class="form-control"  name="size" id="size">
          {{range $key, $value := .Sizes }}
            <option value="{{ $value }}">{{ $key }}</option>  
          {{end}}
      </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how to the value to selected. Thanks

Comment: Please show the code for data retrieval also from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

When you render the template again after the error, you have to set the selected attribute for the option.

```
{{range $key, $value := .Sizes }}
  <option value="{{ $value }}" {{if eq $value .SelectedItem}}selected{{end}}>{{ $key }}</option>  
{{end}}
```

Above, `.SelectedItem` is the variable you passed to template that holds the selected item.

Comment: Thanks Burak,you got me going. Below is the code that did the trick.                                                                                                     <label for="size" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Size</label>
                  <select class="form-control"  name="size" id="size" value= "{{.Size}}">
                  {{range $key, $value := .Sizes }}
                       <option value="{{ $value }}"  {{if eq  $value  $.Size   }} selected {{end}}>{{ $key }}</option>  
                  {{end}}                     
                  </select>